# Message to all connected clients(Winsock)(c++)

Tags: c++, winsock

I have a server, which creates a separate thread for each new client

```
while ((client_socket = accept(server_socket, (sockaddr*)&client_info, &client_addr_size)))
{
    nclients++;
    HOSTENT *hst;
    hst = gethostbyaddr((char*)&client_info.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr, 4, AF_INET);
    printf("+%s [%s] new connect!\n", (hst) ? hst->h_name : "", inet_ntoa(client_info.sin_addr));
    PRINTUSERS;
    DWORD thID;
    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, SexToClient, &client_socket, NULL, &thID);
}
```

Stream function every n seconds sends a  message.(All streams do not do it at the same time).How to send a message to all clients at the same time?(broadcast)

Comment: Do you have a list of active users in the `Server` class? If so, you could just iterate through this list (or map or whatever fits your needs best) sending the message to each.

Comment: But with every client connected a different socket,or am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I cant See Streamfunction. Without the corresponding function I cant give a perfect answer. Normally you would send (asynchron) in a for loop to all clients. The System would teen send the Massage to each Client one After Another. If you want to truly send a Massage to multiple clients at the Same time you need to use multicast.
(= sending one package which will arrive at multiple clients.) Unfortunately this is not possible using TCP, since TCP etablishes a (secure) point to point connection between one host and one client. You would have to use UDP.  Remember that UDP wont care if the packages will arrive in the right Order, are correct or arrive at all.